# How can i merge two fields shown as one in an output of an sql view statement?

Tags: sql, view

I have a table which contains students ID and Their respective Teachers ID . i want to show students with their teachers.For this i get the name of the students and teachers through two other tables named:Honarjo as for student and Morabi as for teacher.
My problem is , i want to have the teacher name as one filed not two separate Name and Family fields.
Here is my Sql codes for view :

```
SELECT        dbo.tblHonarjo.CodeMeli, dbo.tblHonarjo.Name, dbo.tblHonarjo.Family, 

dbo.tblHonarjo.PhoneHome, dbo.tblHonarjo.Mobile, dbo.tblMorabi.Name AS TeacherName, 
                         dbo.tblMorabi.Family AS TeacherFamily
FROM            dbo.tblStudentnDriver INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblHonarjo ON dbo.tblStudentnDriver.SID = dbo.tblHonarjo.CodeMeli INNER JOIN
                         dbo.tblMorabi ON dbo.tblStudentnDriver.TID = dbo.tblMorabi.CodeMeli
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `CONCAT(value1, value2, value3)` to concatenate fields.

For example, in your case you might want to do `CONCAT(TeacherName, " ", TeacherFamily)` to display this format `<TeacherName> <TeacherFamily>`.

Comment: Thank you . But CONCAT accepts only two arguments, How can i Add a space between the two fields?

Comment: True, CONCAT(TeacherName, CONCAT(" ", TeacherFamily)) would do the trick though :)
Seems easier to use + though, if the DB supports it!

Answer (score 2):

There should be some form of Concatenation operator depending on the type of DB you are using, for example in Postgres it is ||, so you can do

`dbo.tblHonarjo.Name || dbo.tblHonarjo.Family`